# How to calculate the minimum radius of a turn at high alpha, without banking?

Tags: aerodynamics

How to calculate the minimum radius of a turn at high alpha, without banking?

One sees the radio control guys flying their planes at 30deg AOA in a 5' circle at walking speed, without banking.

Obviously 99% of GA planes can't fly that slow, but what radius can one fly at slow speeds, , say at 20 deg AOA, 10 mph above stall, say 50mph in something like a Cessna150.......without banking?

Comment: Maybe this is nitpicking, but an aircraft stalls at a specific angle of attack regardless of the airspeed, and that angle is typically 16 degrees.

Comment: @Ben With slats, stall AOA of straight tapered wing can be increased well beyond 20 deg, approaching 30 deg

Comment: I can tell you that absolutely nobody turns an airplane that way.  Nobody.  RC airplanes operate at very low Rns, with absurd power to weight ratios, and no one's life is on the line, so they can do all sorts of things big airplanes don't.  In any case, you would have to establish a skidding turn rate for a given airplane by testing it.

Comment: They do at airshows. lol  :)

Comment: So why isn't it safe at 1.3Vs??

Comment: Re above, is a skidding turn safe?